# How to get first n keys in associative array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, associative-array

I have an array that stores a persons scores in several different subjects, for example:

```
$scores = array(
    'reading' => 80,
    'math' => 85, 
    'science' => 75, 
    'social studies'=> 90, 
    'music' => 95);
```

I need to get a list of the top 3 subjects (keys) as a string:

```
$topScores = "Music, Social Studies, Math";
```

What is a clean and efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Sort the array, get the keys of the array and then the first 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort the array in reverse order keeping association with arsort().  Then take a slice of the array (first three elements).

```
arsort( $scores );
$topScores = array_slice( $scores, 0, 3 );
```

You can then use implode to generate a string from the sliced array.

---

Rizier123 pointed out you wanted the keys in the string, so you'd need to implode the keys.  Something like

```
$topScoresStr = implode( ', ', array_keys( $topScores ) );
```

Comment: Doesn't quite work as a one-liner: 1) arsort returns a bool ;) 2) OP wants the keys

Comment: @Rizier123, yeah, I just looked it up to verify if it was a reference.

Comment: `$scores = array_slices(...)`

Comment: @fusion3k:  Okay, you twisted my arm, I'll put in the assignments :P

Comment: array_slice does not keep integer keys. array_slice($sorted, 0, 2) would give 0 and 1 indices in the resulting array.

Comment: @rela589n the question is asking for associative arrays...

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I came with:

```
arsort($scores);
$scores = array_slice($scores,0,3);
$finalString = null;
foreach($scores as $key => $value){
    $finalString .= ucfirst($key).', ';
}
echo $finalString;
```

Comment: Implode is a better alternative than a loop in this, if they do want the words capitalized, they can call array_filter with ucwords.  ucfirst wouldn't work right for 'Social studies'.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with:

```
$sorted = $scores;
arsort($sorted);
$top_three = array_slice(array_keys($sorted), 0, 3);
$skills = implode(', ',$top_three);
$this->top_skills = ucwords($skills);
```