# Return the indices of the largest + second largest values in a PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, indexing

**Goal:** given a string containing a list of comma-separated float values, return the indices of the largest and second largest floats

- "Largest" and "Second largest" should be sorted numerically (not as strings); e.g., "100" is larger than "2"

**Example:**

- given a string: "11,2,1,100,1.5"
- return the indices: 3 and 0 (corresponding to numeric values 100 and 11)

**What I've tried:**

New to PHP, but I feel like I'm *so* close with the following code, but can't figure out how to get the actual index values:

```
$x_string = "11,2,1,100,1.5";
$x_array = explode(",", $x_string);

// apply floatval to every element of array
function float_alter(&$item) { $item = floatval($item); }
array_walk($x_array, float_alter);

$temp = $x_array;
arsort($temp);

var_dump($temp);
```

Outputs:

> array(5) { [**3**]=> float(100) [**0**]=> float(11) [1]=> float(2) [4]=> float(1.5) [2]=> float(1) }

Comment: You can use `array_keys` to get the list of keys of associative array.

Comment: Thank you so much. For anyone who finds this simple question in the future, the solution would be ```$keys = array_keys($temp);``` and then accessing ```$keys[0]``` and ```$keys[1]```

Comment: I would hammer with [How to get first n keys in associative array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36048038/2943403) if I didn't explicitly want to show you a better way to code this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split and floatval in one step. Then sort descending to have largest first. The keys are still kept.

```
$string = "11,2,1,100,1.5";
$floats = array_map('floatval', explode(',', $string));
arsort($floats, SORT_NUMERIC | SORT_DESC);

print_r($floats);

list($largestKey, $secondLargestKey) = array_keys($floats);
echo "$largestKey, $secondLargestKey";
```

prints

```
Array
(
    [3] => 100
    [0] => 11
    [1] => 2
    [4] => 1.5
    [2] => 1
)
3, 0
```

Comment: `arsort()` with `SORT_DESC` is a tautology.

Comment: LOL, now I notice :D `list($largestKey, $secondLargestKey) = array_keys($floats);` could also be simplified as `[$largestKey, $secondLargestKey] = array_keys($floats);`.

Comment: (I agree in my answer)

Answer (score 0):

There is no benefit in calling `floatval()` on every value after exploding because you are only interested in the keys anyhow.

Just sort your array in DESCending order while evaluating the values as numbers and preserving the original keys.  Here is a simpler approach:

1. Explode
2. Sort
3. Isolate the top two elements
4. Return all keys

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/GGlGM))

```
$array = explode(',', '11,2,1,100,1.5');
arsort($array, SORT_NUMERIC);
var_export(array_keys(array_slice($array, 0, 2, true)));
```

---

Markus's answer could be modified to be this and return the same data, but it generates an unnecessarily long array of keys before truncating (as a means to avoid a function call). ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/TGk42))

```
$array = explode(',', '11,2,1,100,1.5');
arsort($array, SORT_NUMERIC);
[$first, $second] = array_keys($array);
var_export([$first, $second]);
```